# Shell Script/Command to delete all consecutive duplicate occurrences of any word, which are separated by a single space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to delete all consecutive duplicate occurrences of any word, which are separated by a single space. 
I/P :

```
double double toil and trouble
fire burn and cauldron bubble bubble
tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow
creeps in this this petty pace from day toto day
to the last syllable of recorded time time
```

O/P :

```
double toil and trouble
fire burn and cauldron bubble
tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow
creeps in this petty pace from day toto day
to the last syllable of recorded time
```

Tried this

```
cat input.txt | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf("%s%s",$i,FS)}{printf("\n")}'
```

this removes all duplicates, please help here

Comment: This fails if i put something like double double double toil and trouble my my my

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!=$(i+1)){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
    }
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Logical explanation:*** Simply looping through all fields of each line, comparing current field value to its next field value and if its NOT equal then adding its value to variable, when loop is done with execution then printing that variable and nullifying it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{
    printf "%s", $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i != $(i-1)) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
double toil and trouble
fire burn and cauldron bubble
tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow
creeps in this petty pace from day toto day
to the last syllable of recorded time
```